# New API does not return the Watch History

Tags: api, youtube, history, watch

The application that we are developing is related to creating a service that seeks to identify informal learning activities using YouTube as a tool. This is a doctoral thesis and the service aims to provide teachers / educational institutions of learning activity information that are related to the themes seen in the classroom classroom or using a Virtual Learning Environment. All these identifications will be made with the permission of users (students) within the period set by the subject teacher / course.

All the necessary information for our service were available until the new version of the API of the day 15.9.2016 came to not return history information of watched videos that our service needs.

Is there a specific procedure for the release of funds, in view of the launch of the new version? Can you help us?

---

According to the latest revision of the YouTube API
requests to retrieve playlist items (playlistItems.list) for a channel's watch history now return empty lists.
Avaliable in - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history de September 15, 2016.

---

Comment: I think it might be better if you contacted YouTube directly regarding the API changes.  Stack Overflow is here for figuring out the right way to do something, but we can't provide technical support for YouTube's API deprecation.

Comment: Do you know where can i do this? becauce in official website i didn't find anyone way!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Here's one recommendation - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support